# Out of memory Even though my pictures are less than 2 MB

Tags: java, android

I am making a animated login screen...my code is as follows

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    if (i == null) throw new AssertionError();
    i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_pulse);
    AnimationDrawable pro = (AnimationDrawable)i.getDrawable();
    pro.start();
```

but when I execute the app in the emulator, it says

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17280012 byte allocation with 
4194304 free bytes and 15MB until OOM
```

though my my drawable files are less than 2mb and even the following code doesn't help.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: The image file may be 2mb, but that is compressed (e.g. with jpeg). When loaded into memory it has to be decoded to raw pixel data which is typically be many times larger. One of the images of your animation is 17mb in memory as seen in the error message.

Comment: what is your image resolution ?

Comment: so how to deal with it.....because i am clueless...there are 33 frames for my animation....each frame is about 30 kb png.....

Comment: @GaneshPatil...800x600 is my resolution

Comment: "800x600 is my resolution" -- the image that you are loading is much larger than this. Where exactly is this drawable resource on your development machine? (`res/drawable/`? `res/drawable-nodpi/`? some other drawable directory?)

Comment: its in my res/drawable.....my res its self is 1.7 mb only....

Answer (score 0):

> Please add this on your **manifest** file and then look at the magic,

- `android:largeHeap="true"`
- `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

Happy coding!!

Comment: First, not all devices actually allocate a larger heap. Second, apps that request a larger heap cause problems for users, as the larger heap kicks other apps out of memory sooner. Only egocentric developers would consider an animation to be justification for a large heap. Third, even in the best-case scenario, this merely postpones the problem, as eventually you will fragment the larger heap. Fourth, the developer is already requesting a large heap.

Comment: @CommonsWare what are the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some imageloader library. That will fix oom.

1. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
2. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
3. Uml
4. [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/)

out of these Glide is best :)

**the gradle dependencies:**

```
// if you need jar ,please download it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide
compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '3.8.0'
```

**the sample code:**

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(your drawable)
                .override(yoursize, yoursize)
                 .into(new Target<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStop() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroy() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super Drawable> glideAnimation) {
                       imageview.setImageDrawable(resource);
                       //start animation here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(Drawable placeholder) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setRequest(Request request) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public Request getRequest() {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how this addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

tru this on anroidmenifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how this addresses the question and how it improves upon other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, move the image from `res/drawable/` to `res/drawable-nodpi/`. `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and so you are saying that 800x600 is the resolution that you want for `-mdpi` screens (around 160dpi). On higher density devices, Android will automatically scale such resources to keep the same physical size (5" x 3.5"), and that is increasing the memory consumption of your image.

While that change will help, you will still run into `OutOfMemoryErrors` on many devices. You will need to get rid of this animation entirely, or replace it with something else that does not require ~60MB of heap space (800 pixels x 600 pixels x 4 bytes/pixel x 33 images).

Comment: is it possible that i resize the image and then use the animation?

Comment: @nithinsampath: Having lower-resolution frames will reduce the heap requirements. Whether it will be sufficient to avoid `OutOfMemoryErrors` depends on how low you go with the resolution. And then you might not like what it looks like.